# Programming Error "if item not in list"

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am writing a word game where a player makes words out of an x letter hand, and when they make a word the letters in the word are subtracted from the players hand.

I am trying to see if an entered word is in my wordlist using this function:

```
def is_valid_word(word, hand, word_list):
    worddict = get_frequency_dict(word)
    if word not in word_list:
        return False

    for x in LETTERS:
        numlettershand = hand.get(x)
        numlettersword = worddict.get(x)
        if numlettershand == None and numlettersword != None:
            return False
        if numlettershand != None and numlettersword != None:
            if numlettershand - numlettersword < 0:
                return False

   return True
```

It gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\Oleg\Desktop\Sams Stuff\programming\MIT\Problem Set 3\ps3a.py", line 112, in <module>
    play_hand(deal_hand(HAND_SIZE), load_words)
  File "C:\Users\Oleg\Desktop\Sams Stuff\programming\MIT\Problem Set 3\ps3a.py", line 106, in play_hand
    if is_valid_word(word, hand, wordlist) == True:
  File "C:\Users\Oleg\Desktop\Sams Stuff\programming\MIT\Problem Set 3\ps3a.py", line 75, in is_valid_word
    if word not in word_list:
TypeError: argument of type 'function' is not iterable
```

Comment: So `word_list` is a function object; presumably `load_words` is that function, passed on by `play_hand`?

Comment: You'll need to post more code than that... it's likely that the bug is in the calling code.

Comment: You've passed a reference to a function. Do you have a function called `wordlist`?

Comment: If any of these answers helped you, please vote them up and accept one, otherwise, please add more information to your question so we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call load_words: `load_words()`

Answer (score 1):

The argument `wordlist` is a function, not an iterable. Did you mean to call it before passing it to `is_valid_word()`?

Comment: This should have been a comment, Ignacio; a redundant one at that.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: "The error is in your calling code; verify that you've passed all arguments correctly." is short, but it's an answer. Perhaps not the best possible one in the world, but still valid.

Comment: For all we know the OP mixed up a variable name somewhere; there is too little context here to make any kind of meaningful answer.

Comment: *shrug* This is true, but I've worked with less (and subsequently nailed it).

Comment: Thanks, i apologize that it was kind of a dumb question.